# Need help printing 2 Fractal trees

Tags: javascript, fractals

Yesterday, I had asked for help in printing out a Fractal tree. That question was answered, but now I am trying to implement one more rule into my code. And while implementing it in my code, it is printing the tree, but not at the right coordinates. Here is a link to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619855/need-help-in-printing-fractal-tree). I would like to print both the trees side-by-side instead of on top of each other. So my question is how do I achieve that? Thanks for all the help.

Here is the new code:

```
var sentence = "F";
var sentence2 = "F";
var sentence3 = "X";

var rules = [];
rules[0] = {
    a: "F",
    b: "F[+F]F[-F]F"
}
var rulesB = [];
rulesB[0] = {
    a: "F",
    b: "FF-[-F+F+F]+[+F-F-F]"
}
/*
var rulesC = [];
rulesC[0] = {
    a: "F",
    b: "FF"
}
rulesC[1] = {
    a: "X",
    b: "F-[[X]+X]+F[+FX]-X"
}
*/

var x = 50;  // starting x
var y = 400;  // starting y
var y_stack = [];  // save & restore don't handle coordinates
var y_stack2 = []
draw();


function turtle(sentence, context){
    for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {

        var current = sentence.charAt(i);

        if (current == "F") {
            y -= 20;
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        } else if (current == "+") {
            context.translate(x, y);
            context.rotate((20 * Math.PI) / 180);
            context.translate(-x, -y);
        } else if (current == "-") {
            context.translate(x, y);
            context.rotate((-20 * Math.PI) / 180);
            context.translate(-x, -y);
        } else if (current == "[") {
            context.save();
            y_stack.push(y);
        } else if (current == "]") {
            context.restore();
            y = y_stack.pop();
            context.moveTo(x, y)
        }
    }
}

function generate(sentence){
    var nextSentence = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        var current = sentence.charAt(i);
        var found = false;

        for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++ ) {
            if (current == rules[j].a) {
                found = true;
                nextSentence += rules[j].b;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            nextSentence += current;
        }
    }

    return nextSentence;
}

function turtle2(sentence2, context){
    for (var i = 0; i < sentence2.length; i++) {        

        var current = sentence2.charAt(i);

        if (current == "F") {
            y -= 20;
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        } else if (current == "+") {
            context.translate(x, y);
            context.rotate((22.5 * Math.PI) / 180);
            context.translate(-x, -y);
        } else if (current == "-") {
            context.translate(x, y);
            context.rotate((-22.5 * Math.PI) / 180);
            context.translate(-x, -y);
        } else if (current == "[") {
            context.save();
            y_stack2.push(y);
        } else if (current == "]") {
            context.restore();
            y = y_stack2.pop();
            context.moveTo(x, y)
        }
    }
}

function generate2(sentence2){
    var nextsentence2 = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < sentence2.length; i++) {
        var current = sentence2.charAt(i);
        var found = false;

        for (var j = 0; j < rulesB.length; j++ ) {
            if (current == rulesB[j].a) {
                found = true;
                nextsentence2 += rulesB[j].b;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            nextsentence2 += current;
        }
    }

    return nextsentence2;
}

function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

   // context.moveTo(x, y);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sentence = generate(sentence);
    }

    console.log(sentence);
    turtle(sentence, context);


    //context.moveTo(100,400);
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        sentence2 = generate2(sentence2);
    }

    console.log(sentence2);
    turtle2(sentence2, context);

}
/*
function turtle3(){
    //resetMatrix();
    context.translate(width/6, height);
    for (var n = 0; n < sentence3.length; n++){
        var current = sentence3.charAt(n);
        if (current == "F"){
            context.stroke("#28b232");
            context.lineTo(0, -len3);
            context.translate(0, -len3);
        }else if (current == "X"){
            context.stroke("#024d08");
            context.lineTo(-len3, 0);
            context.translate(0, -len3);
        }else if (current == "+"){
            context.rotate(angle2);
        }else if (current == "-"){
            context.rotate(-angle2);
        }else if (current == "["){
            save();
        }else if (current == "]"){
            restore();
        }
    }
}

*/

/*
function generate3(){
    len2 *= .5;
    var nextSentence3 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < sentence3.length; i++){
        var current3 = sentence3.charAt(i);
        var found3 = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < rulesC.length; j++ ){
            if (current3 == rulesC[j].a){
                found3 = true;
                nextSentence3 += rulesC[j].b;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found3){
            nextSentence3 += current3;
        }
    }
    sentence3 = nextSentence3;
    turtle3();
}*/
```